# slick carousel has a 1px height on server, local environment 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm using the slick carousel. I want the background-url to have a 100% height

here is my carousel
http://jsfiddle.net/84c8gvkt/3/

HTML:

```
<section>
<div class="carousel-container">
    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/01/a4/e9/fa/los-perdidos-hot-springs.jpg');">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-image:url('http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/01/a4/e9/fa/los-perdidos-hot-springs.jpg');">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    $('.carousel-container').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 3000,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    autoplay: false,
    pauseOnHover: true,

});
```

CSS

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.fill {
    padding: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
}
.fill:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

I can't figure out where it's  going wrong.

Can you help me? Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be coming from the fact that neither your `section` or your `.carousel-container` have 100% height, nor do any of the elements generated by your slick carousel.

The easy fixed would simply be to use viewport units instead of a percentage on the `.fill` element.

Try making the following change:

```
.fill {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

The `vh` unit is pretty well supported across all browsers. [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

This may not necessarily be the best way to do it for what you're trying to achieve, but just a suggestion.